# Pass an option to a makefile

Tags: make, parameter

### Makefile

```
my_test:
ifdef $(toto)
        @echo 'toto is defined'
else
        @echo 'no toto around'
endif
```

### Expected behavior

```
$ make my_test
no toto around

$ make my_test toto
toto is defined
```

### Current behavior

```
$ make my_test
no toto around

$ make my_test toto
no toto around
make: *** No rule to make target `toto'.  Stop.
```

When I run `make my_test` I get the else text as expected `no toto around`. However

```
make my_test toto
no toto around
make: *** No rule to make target `toto'.  Stop.
```

**Makefile version**

```
 $ make -v
   GNU Make 3.81
```

**SLE version**

```
$ cat /etc/*release
  VERSION_ID="11.4"
  PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"
```

### PS

The point is to make `make my_test` verbose if `toto`, if `toto` not given then the command will run silently

Comment: Seems to work without error messages when using GNU `make` 4.2.1.

Comment: @Kusalananda this should work in many servers, so it should be make 3.81 compliant too

Comment: In what way does make “behave weirdly”? You ask to build `toto`, there's no rule to build `toto`, make tells you that there's no rule to build `toto`. What else did you expect?

Comment: If you want Make to check if `toto` is defined then you'll need to define it - `make my_test toto=1` might be what you're after?

Comment: @garethTheRed yes that works for me but the value of toto isn't interesting for me, all I need is "is toto passed to my command or not"

Comment: @smarber It matters to `make` whether `toto` was passed as a target or as a variable assignment on the command line.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see. In this case isn't it possible to pass an option/flag like `-t` ?

Comment: @smarber You can't pass arguments to `make` without `make` interpreting them as its own command line flags, targets or variable assignments.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to remove the dollar around toto, and also pass toto from the command line differently

*Command line*

```
make toto=1  my_test
```

*Makefile*

```
my_test:
ifdef toto
        @echo 'toto is defined'
else
        @echo 'no toto around'
endif
```

Comment: Actually I wanted to use `ifdef` because the value of `toto` is not interesting in my case, I only need to know if it's here or not

Comment: @smarber So is `toto` supposed to be a target or not? Please edit your question to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: @Gilles toto is juste an option that I want to pass to `make my_test`, if toto is given I do some extra actions

Comment: @smarber Ok, then amisax's answer is what you need.

Comment: Is there any way to not specify that `toto=1`? Just `make my_test toto`? Because `ifdef` checks that `toto` is defined, not whether it equals 1, 2, or 48

Answer (score 1):

You can use these Makefile contents, trick is the [`filter` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions):

```
my_test:
ifeq (toto, $(filter toto,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
        @echo 'toto is defined'
else
        @echo 'no toto around'
endif
        @echo run command $(if $(filter toto,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),--verbose,--normally)

%:
        @:
```

Results:

```
$ make my_test
no toto around
run command --normally

$ make my_test toto
toto is defined
run command --verbose

$ make toto my_test
toto is defined
run command --verbose

$ make my_test totofofo
no toto around
run command --normally
```

Comment: Interesting, but the problem is that it silenced any errors when misspelling a command: Now `make my_test toto` works but `make mytest toto` returns nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Makefile can be trick, normaly i do some thing like

```
# turn them into do-nothing targets
$(eval toto:;@:)

my_test:
ifeq (toto, $(filter toto,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
        @echo 'toto is defined'
else
        @echo 'no toto around'
endif
```